# How can I remove the whitespace from my website using the clip-path property?

Tags: html, css, properties, polygon, clip-path

I'm working on my portfolio site and created a unique header by applying the `clip-path` property as shown in my attachment. The code I used worked successfully. However, there's now a bit of whitespace on each side of the corner in between the two sections of my website that I'd like to have removed. I'm including a copy of the selector and properties applied below:

HTML:

```
<header class="container">
        <p>
...nurtures growth through complex group problem solving. I accomplish this by applying                        active listening skills, focusing on soft metrics to drive key results, and take a forward thinking
approach when setting up policies and processes. I believe preventing stagnation is crucial in an industry that's constantly adapting and growing day by day.
        </p>         
</header>

<!-- ********************* PROJECTS / PORTFOLIO ********************* -->

<section class="projects">
        <div class="content-wrap divider">
          <h2>Featured Projects</h2>
          <p>
            View selected projects below, more information can be found at
            <a class="btn" href="#">test.com</a>
          </p>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    height: 95vh;
    background: #2F3061;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80vh, 50% 100%, 0 80vh);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.projects {
    background: #F7FFF7;
}
```

[image: clip-pathed site page header]

I'd like to have this whitespace removed, but without changing the `background-color` of the section below to white. I'm thinking the best way to approach this would be to apply the same `clip-path` property to the "Featured Projects" section, but with different values perhaps to offset what I did to the above? Would anybody know the way to go about fine-tuning this formula and how to go about handling this?

Comment: Could you put more of the site's code in here (e.g. for the "Featured Products" at least)?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback/suggestions! Up until today I've only ever used this to seek knowledge, never post things myself lol

Comment: No problem, I saw that. Welcome to fully using the site. 

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you want - is it that that white bit (I won't say 'white space' as that has rather specific CSS connotations) should have that pale greeny color?

Comment: @AHaworth yes correct, I want to have the blank space filled with the pale green-like color. I'm thinking if I give the projects selector a clip=path: polygon() property with the right parameters I should be able to accomplish this but that's only speculation at this point.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this would be to use pseudo elements on the container to paint the pointed background and to include the pale green.

This snippet puts a the green background on the before pseudo element and the blue one on the after pseudo element and uses clip-path as in the original code to create the blue shape.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 95vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container::before {
  background: #F7FFF7;
}

.container::after {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 80vh, 50% 100%, 0 80vh);
  background: #2F3061;
}

.projects {
  background: #F7FFF7;
}
```

```html
<header class="container">
  <p>
    ...nurtures growth through complex group problem solving. I accomplish this by applying active listening skills, focusing on soft metrics to drive key results, and take a forward thinking approach when setting up policies and processes. I believe preventing
    stagnation is crucial in an industry that's constantly adapting and growing day by day.
  </p>
</header>

<!-- ********************* PROJECTS / PORTFOLIO ********************* -->

<section class="projects">
  <div class="content-wrap divider">
    <h2>Featured Projects</h2>
    <p>
      View selected projects below, more information can be found at
      <a class="btn" href="#">test.com</a>
    </p>
```